How to fetch wifi saved passwords on Android whithout rooting?
How do I fetch wifi saved passwords through termux (pure bash) in android whithout rooting the device ?
Here is the code that I've marked till now , but not worked
code
adb root

pulling the file
adb pull /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf .

display the context of the file (saved passwords)
cat wpa_supplicant.conf


Hi Yogya, welcome to Stack Apps! This question does not appear to be about the Stack Exchange API or a script or browser extension for Stack Exchange. To get an answer from users that have the expertise about the topic of your question you'll have to find and then re-post on the proper site. Check How do I ask a good question and What is on topic on the target site to make sure your post is in good shape. Your question is definitely off-topic and better deleted here.
